# Xamarin/PHP, I want to make my Jarray to a JObject, either in C# (Xamarin) or in my PHP-code

Tags: c#, php, xamarin

I want to make my Jarray into a JObject, but I am not sure where I should do it. In xamarin or in PHP.

So I will start off giving you my array that I have done in PHP and it looks like this:

```
$contacts = array(); 

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt))
{
    $contact = array(
        "ID" => $row['ProduktID'],
        "Name" => $row['ProduktNamn'],
    );
}

echo json_encode($contacts, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

And this is my code in Xamarin C#,

```
static public async Task<JArray> getOurMainInfo() //Make it J0bject immediately? Or somehow transform it inside this function?
{
    var httpClientRequest = new HttpClient ();

    var result = await httpClientRequest.GetAsync ("http://localhost/getMyPhp.php");

    var resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();
    var jsonResult = JArray.Parse (resultString).ToObject();

    return jsonResult;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A JArray is a JToken which is a JObject... if JArray is a Json.net json array..

Also, you're sending an empty array as you're not adding the contacts to it...

Anyway, if you can don't use directly these clases, first create a consistent model on PHP and then parse it on the xamarin part:

PHP:

```
    $contacts = array(); 

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt))
    {

        $contact = new stdClass;
        $contact->ID = $row['ProduktID'];
        $contact->Name = $row['ProduktNamn'];
        $contacts[] = $contact;

    }

    echo json_encode($contacts, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

And then on Xamarin:

```
    public class Contact
    {
        public string ID{ get; set; } //change to the correct type
        public string Name{ get; set; }
    }

    //...

    static public async Task<List<Contact>> getOurMainInfo() //Make it J0bject immediately? Or somehow transform it inside this function?
    {
        var httpClientRequest = new HttpClient ();

        var result = await httpClientRequest.GetAsync ("http://localhost/getMyPhp.php");

        var resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();
        var jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Contact>>(resultString);

        return jsonResult;

}
```

Comment: When I write "System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine (jsonResult);" out in the log it gives me the project name + contact. I want to be able to type in my log: jsonResult ["Name"] like i can with a JObject

Comment: Try my solution, you can write result[0].Name, a lot better, also, if you only have one contact then don't pass an array, pass the object itself.

Comment: And if you pass a JArray then you must write jsonResult[0]["Name"], it's an array, an array has no property named "Name"...

Comment: Is it not possible to just get it as a j0bject somehow? I am very used to that format so it would help me alot.

Comment: if you want a JObject instead of a strongly typed class, just use JObject.Parse(resultString);

Comment: If I replace my public async task with JObject and below JObject.Parse (resultstring) I get this error: "Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1."

Comment: If i only replace the JObject.Parse(resultString);  from Array I get this error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray'

Comment: you need to modify the PHP to return a single object instead of an array

Comment: Yes, I am working on that right now. Not quite sure how to replace the array as of now but I am googling like a maniac as we speak!! Any hints or tips is greatly appreciated. Cheers