# How do I modify this PHP code to return nested results

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get this as a single object because I work with a JObject on the frontend.

I got an array at the moment but I am unsure how i should modify it so it returns a single object instead.

This is the code:

```
$contacts = array(); 

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt))
        {

            $contact = array("ID" => $row['ProduktID'],
                             "Name" => $row['ProduktNamn'],
                             "Number" => $row['ProduktPris']);

            array_push($contacts, $contact);
        }

        echo json_encode($contacts, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

And the goal is for it to look something like this with "results" as well so I can reach the whole thing:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean a single object?  Don't loop and don't push onto the array if you don't want multiple elements in the array.

Comment: I want to create the json as the picture I mentioned above

Comment: What are you getting now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To wrap your array of contacts in an object with a single `results` property:

```
echo json_encode(array('results' => $contacts), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: I think this is what he actually wants, regardless of the confusing wording of his question.  I was about to post it with a link to http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6fa069cea33765bb695430c5555b1011178d1c29

Comment: I am sorry for being confusing! This did it though. Thanks alot guys. Amazing feedback and support. I am fairly new so this is amazing. Thx again.

Comment: Onto the next issue :) The life of a beginner programmer ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use typecasting to convert an array to an object:

```
$object = (object) $array_name;
```

or manually convert it into an object

```
$object = object;
foreach($arr as $key => $value)
{
    $object->$key = $value;
}
```

Comment: Now I dont get 1 object I think. When I do it Each row gets "0" and the next one "1" etc.

Comment: Like this: {
    "0": {
        "ID": "43",
        "Name": "pro2",
        "Number": "pris2"
    },
    "1": {
        "ID": "42",
        "Name": "Produkt1",
        "Number": "Pris1"
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Like this? Keep in mind an object is different then an array and your question is rather confusing.

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)){
        $contact[] = [
          "ID" => $row['ProduktID'],
          "Name" => $row['ProduktNamn'],
          "Number" => $row['ProduktPris']
        ];
    }

    json_encode(['result' => $contact]); // Forget the JSON_PRETTY_PRINT.
```

Using this method `[]`, it will use the first available numeric index starting with 0. This way you don't have to push an array.

Comment: I do not want it as an array. I want to send the info as a object. Just like the image I showed. Because I want to work with it as a JObject in my frontend

Comment: @William.John, you're sending a JSON string, not an array.  json_encode will encode it whether it's a PHP array or a PHP object.  It makes no difference.

Comment: Hm okay. I was told otherwise in my previous thread (where I show my front end as well) You can take a look here if u want to see if there is something wrong in my code there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35705061/xamarin-php-i-want-to-make-my-jarray-to-a-jobject-either-in-c-sharp-xamarin/35705407#35705407

Comment: @William.John As Devon said, your output is JSON its the array structure you need to worry about. And seeing the comment in Sudoscience answer this code would suffice.

Comment: I think Viktor just nailed it. I will try it and see